# Outputting data from variables in coder

Tags: psychopy

I'm working in PsychoPy to design an experiment. It's almost complete, but I'm trying to output a few variables that I created in a code component into my data file for the experiment, and I haven't been able to figure out how to do that. Here is some relevant code:

```
if branch == 1:
    if money.keys == 'left':
        feedback = 'You chose $10 immediately'
        TotalNow = TotalNow + 10
        add = (amount - 10)/2 
        amount = add + amount
    elif money.keys == 'right':
        feedback = 'You chose $%.2f in two weeks' %(amount)
        TotalLater = TotalLater + amount
        TLtext = '%.2f' %(TotalLater)
        amount = (amount + 10)/2
    elif money.keys in ['', [], None]:
        feedback = 'You did not make a choice. No reward given.'
        amount = amount
if branch == 2:
    if money.keys == 'right':
        feedback = 'You chose $10 immediately'
        TotalNow = TotalNow + 10
        add = (amount - 10)/2 
        amount = add + amount
    elif money.keys == 'left':
        feedback = 'You chose $%.2f in two weeks' %(amount)
        TotalLater = TotalLater + amount
        TLtext = '%.2f' %(TotalLater)
        amount = (amount + 10)/2
    elif money.keys in ['', [], None]:
        feedback = 'You did not make a choice. No reward given.'
        amount = amount
```

I would like to output the following variables into the data file: 'TotalLater', 'TotalNow', and 'amount'. I've tried a few things, but it doesn't seem that I'm close. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `addData()` method of the current experiment handler (which by default is named `thisExp` in Builder:

```
# specify each column name and its associated variable:
thisExp.addData('TotalLater', TotalLater)
thisExp.addData('TotalNow', TotalNow)
thisExp.addData('amount', amount)
```

Do this at the end of the relevant routine to save the current values for that trial.

Answer (score 0):

If you like writing your own code, and want to learn a bit more Python, look into dictionaries which store things as "key" and "value" pairs. You start somewhere are the beginning of your program to create the dictionary with all the keys you want, and then as the program runs you store the values in the dictionary. Before the first trial you can use a function to write the keys as the column headings of a spreadsheet, and then each trial add lines with the values. For instance:

```
import csv ; #to use the spreadsheet export

def createDataFile(fh,d):
    #fh is the handle for a file you created
    #d is the name of the dictionary you have created
    cdw = csv.DictWriter(fh,fieldnames = d.keys(),quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    cdw.writeheader()
    return(cdw)
```

Here are some example lines from a dictionary where I am setting the values for the conditions of an expriments, note that some of these lines have keys where the value is another dictionary - the dictionaries are nested.

```
dty['tstX'] = dty['xoffset']['r']
dty['cbCon'] = dict(r = dty['tstCon'], l = dty['stdCon'])
dty['cbOri'] = dict(r =  dty['tstStrOri'], l =  dty['stdStrOri'])
dty['stdX'] = dty['xoffset']['l']
```

In your case you would have values for `dty['amt'] = amount` and at the end of a trial, you would use the function `writerow()` to put the latest values in their right place in the spreadsheet.

I know this is a lot more detailed, and less intuitive then the above, but you can use dictionaries in lots of places, and they are pretty darn handy.

As I have been cutting and pasting from a file of ours, the above code will likely not work out of the box for you, but will hopefully provide some useful guide posts for your own explorations.